# how to select the values in the table in this format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `table1`

```
Item_Name      |   Type     |   Qty   | Amount

   A                Like         2       10
   B                Love         1       20
   C                Ours         1       10
   A                Love         1       10
   A                Like         1       10
   B                Ours         1       10
```

I need a o/p as below

```
Item_Name            Like | Love | Ours      Like | Love | Ours  
                            Amount                 Qty

  A                   20     10     0          3      1      0
  B                   0      20     10         0      1      1
  C                   0      0      10         0      0      1
```

How can i achieve the desired o/p. I am not able to achieve the same. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use grouping and conditional aggregates to get the output that you need:

```
SELECT Item_Name,
    SUM(Case WHEN Type='Like' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Like_Amount,
    SUM(Case WHEN Type='Love' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Love_Amount,
    SUM(Case WHEN Type='Ours' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Ours_Amount,
    SUM(Case WHEN Type='Like' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS Like_Qty,
    SUM(Case WHEN Type='Love' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS Love_Qty,
    SUM(Case WHEN Type='Ours' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS Ours_Qty
FROM table1
GROUP BY Item_Name
ORDER BY Item_Name
```

Above query works if list of possible values in `Type` column is fixed. If these values can change, you need to use other approaches (e.g. `PIVOT`)

Comment: I think you need to get confirm regarding 'Type' is static or dynamic ? If dynamic then your given solution won't work.

Comment: @MihirShah Thanks, I added explanation to my answer

Comment: @dotnetom thanks for the reply. I will try the same. Also is it possible to give a soln with Pivot also?